# Angular UI Router - "could not resolve state" with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am *very* simply trying to use the Angular UI router. I have just two states are the moment and they are crazy simple. Here's a bit of my app:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $stateProvider
            .state('items', {
                url: '/items',
                templateUrl: 'src/components/Items/list.html',
                controller: 'ItemsController'
            })
            .state('item-details', {
                url: '/item-details/:itemId',
                templateUrl: 'src/components/Items/details.html',
                controller: 'ItemDetailsController'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/items');

    });
```

And a bit of my HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="item-details/{{item.id}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

When I type `item-details/194` manually into my browser, things work like a charm. But, when I try to follow the link I've listed above, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'item-details/194' from state 'items' at Object.y.transitionTo
```

I'm hoping I'm doing something pretty obvious, but this is proving to be trickier than I expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong syntax for your `ui-sref` directive. Instead of doing this:

```
<a ui-sref="item-details/{{item.id}}">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

You can pass parameters to the state like this:

```
<a ui-sref="item-details({itemId: item.id})">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

You can see an example of it in the [documentation for ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref).

Comment: Silly syntax gotchas! This works perfectly. Thank you for the complete explanation.

Comment: Just a quick note: the link you've referenced for ui-sref documentation does not work.

Comment: @amlyhamm just made an update..now it will be working..You could also look at mine answer which has some extras that would improve your code..

Answer (score 2):

All above answers are correct

As an additional improvisation, it looks like `item-details` can actually become a child route of `item`

I'd suggest you to change your `item-details` route to `item.details`, this will say that details route has inherited from `item` state.

```
.state('item.details', {
      url: '/item-details/:itemId',
      templateUrl: 'src/components/Items/details.html',
      controller: 'ItemDetailsController'
});
```

Then your `ui-sref` will become.

```
<a ui-sref=".details({itemId: item.id})">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @pankajparkar. I was hoping to just get a simple example working, first. This is likely the direction I will head next!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a ui-sref="item-details({ itemId: item.id })">{{ item.name }}</a>
```